# How do I set the color of the action bar using palette library?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, palette

I have a bitmap which I use to display an image from firebase in an imageview. I want both the status bar and the action bar's colors to be adjusted by the vibrant color of the pictures from the database. I searched for how to do this, and have the following code below

```
      Palette.from(myBitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {

              android.app.ActionBar bar=setBackgrounddrawable(palette.getVibrantColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary)));
             getWindow().setStatusBarColor(palette.getVibrantColor(getResources().getColor(R.colorPrimary)));
        }
    });
```

But I get an error on the line of code for get action bar saying 'set background drawable cannot be applied to int' When I remove the line of code for setting color of the actionbar only the status bar color is set and not the action bar, how can I set the color of the action bar as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As You see, `setBackgroundDrawable()` receive a param what type is `Drawable`,

but you pass an `Int Color` value in, then you got the error.

---

I do not test it, but You can give it a try with:

`setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(palette.getVibrantColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))));`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it will be easy to use Toolbar?

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mainPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/logo_vector_dark"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Setup toolbar in onCreate of Activity:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Change color:

```
Palette.from(myBitmap).generate(new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {      
        toolbar.setBackgroundColor(palette.getVibrantColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent)));
    }
});
```